# DSLR Camera with no wireless connectivity (WiFi, Bluetooth, GPS)?

Tags: dslr, camera, wireless

I would like to buy a new DSLR camera but I'm concerned about security. I was wondering if there's a camera on the market that doesn't have built-in wireless connectivity to it or has an option to physically disable it.

Comment: To my knowledge, the ones with it requires the camera's software to disable it. Is this a concern for battery life, or a security issue?

Comment: "Concerned about security" is far too vague. Whose security, under what circumstances, from what vector? This information drives the answer.

Answer (score 3):

**As far as I know, they all allow disabling**. In fact, all the ones I have direct experience with require specifically enabling Bluetooth or WiFi in order to use it.

My Nikon D7200 supports WiFi but it's default disabled. Simply enabling the WiFi on the as shipped camera does indeed put it in an open insecure mode, but the Nikon App will allow you to change it to a secure WPA2 protocol.

**The biggest potential security concern with a camera, especially on a phone but also newer DSLRs, is recording GPS location data in the pictures.** It's a nice reference value in principle, but telling everyone where you or your children live is probably not a good idea. Fortunately **most** picture sites strip this EXIF information out, but be aware that it exists.

EDIT

Per Scottbb comments:

My answer assumes that your interest is in *personal security* vice conforming to corporate security environments.

Comment: OP specifically asked if cameras had a **physical** option to disable wireless/Bluetooth/GPS. From a security standpoint (meaning, using or operating in an environment with strict security rules), a software enablement/disablement is not secure. That is, how does a person responsible for a site's security trust that WiFi was turned off? If it's a physical switch, it can be glued in position, or even have the switch physically removed. But how does a site supervisor guarantee that a software switch stays off?

Comment: For such situations, GPS isn't necessarily the primary security concern. **Data exfiltration** is usually the primary concern.

Comment: @scottbb - I can address that in the information security forum if you like, but it's probably not appropriate here.

Comment: @scottb Not even. The switch could have been moved elsewhere and activated from the outside (reed switch).

Comment: @xenoid I don't follow your comment.

Comment: @scottbb one could divert the wire to the apparently glued switch to some invisible reed switch (inside the camera)  that you can actuate with a magnet (outside the camera). Also, some physical switches are just read/sensed by the firmware and an altered firmware could just ignore them.

Comment: @xenoid Understood. Big picture, that my original comment was about, was not about absolute security. Physical lack or disablement of wireless is usually about a particular site that wants/needs a camera, but site security rules prohibit wireless capability. Devices that are deemed "site safe" are almost always asset tracked, and their access and use is controlled and tracked. So it's procedurally difficult for somebody to modify it after it was cleared for use and tracked, access-controlled, etc.

Answer (score 3):

**Buy a used older camera.**

My primary DSLR is a Nikon D90, which has absolutely no wireless connections. I bought it used a couple of years ago. One is for sale on Kijiji right now less than an hours drive away from me, and you will probably find one if you look.